# Machine learning graphics card - half precision performance

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, gpu

Are there any consumer level graphics cards (i.e. less than, say, $1500) that have decent half precision (fp16) support?

The latest Titan X was rumoured to have native fp16 support but that didn't turn out to be true. Are there any others that support fp16, maybe on older architectures (but are still semi-decent for deep learning)?